# Is it possible to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert on an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: collections, ienumerable, mstest, icollection

I have a testing scenario where I want to check if two collections are equal. I have found the class `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert`, but it only works on `ICollection<T>`. Since I'm testing a repository for Entity Framework, and thus need to compare `IObjectSet<T>`s, that won't do - `IObjectSet<T>` doesn't implement `ICollection<T>`.

Is there any way I can use this class to compare the collecitons, or do I have to create my own implementation? (And why the heck didn't the Microsoft team make the class work with `IEnumerable<T>` instead, as that is the "base interface" for collections?)

**EDIT:** This is my test code:

```
// Arrange
var fakeContext = new FakeObjectContext();
var dummies = fakeContext.Dummies;
var repo = new EFRepository<DummyEntity>(fakeContext);

// Act
var result = repo.GetAll();

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(result, NullErrorMessage(MethodName("GetAll")));
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IEnumerable<DummyEntity>), IncorrectTypeMessage(MethodName("GetAll"), typeof(IEnumerable<DummyEntity>)));
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(dummies.ToList(), result.ToList());
```

The `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` call on the last line fails, stating that the elements at index 0 are not equal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cheeky option (not quite as much info though) is to assert that `expected.SequenceEqual(actual)` returns `true`.

You could write a wrapper method that forces a collection (`.ToList()` on each)? But to be honest you might as well just call `.ToList()` in the unit test code:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToList(), actual.ToList()); // but tidier...
```

Comment: With `.ToList()` calls on all my collections, the code compiles. However, I am unable to write a test I can pass - see the code I provided in an edit to my post.

Comment: Turns out implementing `.Equals()` on `DummyEntity` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comparing result sets you might want to use [CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent%28VS.80%29.aspx) which will ignore the order. You should also make sure you have implemented Equals on the type of elements you are comparing.

Comment: I actually do want the assertion to care about order, but implementing `.Equals()` in combination with calling `.ToList()` on the collections (which I would have had to do anyway to use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`, which is why he got the rep and not you) did the trick. Thanks!